# Unable to self-register a device in AD

Tags: active-directory

I am a Linux guy who doesn't know a whole lot about Active Directory, so I am looking for ideas on how to figure out what's going on here. Of course, if you can tell me exactly what's wrong and how to fix it I will also be very grateful. :)

I have a client who has a Sharp MFP that is supposed to be able to self-register as a Computer in the domain. The only configurable options on the MFP are the domain name and the "Domain Registration User" (and password). Trouble is, even when we use a Domain Admin (who can manually add a device), the MFP always returns with a error message to the effect that the configured user may not have sufficient privileges. It is NOT due to a wrong password because that generates a different (and appropriate) error message.

I have looked at a Wireshark trace but, of course, all the relevant LDAP stuff are encrypted. There is considerable logging in the MFP itself but it doesn't include what is actually sent (and received) - only high-level stuff.

I have tried this on my own DC in my lab and it works fine every time - I am not able to replicate the error!

Some questions that come to mind:

- Is it possible that the client has some sort of policy that prevents devices from auto-registering?
- Is it possible to actually see the LDAP transaction data? If so, how?
- The client has multiple DCs. Would that have an effect?

Thank you very much for any and all ideas/suggestions/solutions.

Comment: Have you tried pre-staging the device in AD?

Comment: Are all of the domain controllers writeable?

Comment: All the DCs are writable.